# Splitting a String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to split a String in Haskell.

My inicial String would look something like

```
["Split a String in Haskell"]
```

and my expected output would be:

```
["Split","a","String","in","Haskell"].
```

From what i've seen, words and lines don't work here, because i have the type [String] instead of just String.

I've tried Data.List.Split, but no luck there either.

Comment: "From what i've seen, words and lines don't work here, because i have the type [String] instead of just String." How is that a problem, and what do you expect splitting a string to do if you just get a string out at the end?

Comment: it is an exercise i'm doing. @Cubic i got stuck because of the  [String] type, and i could not use words or split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Data.List

split = (>>= words)

main = print $ split ["Split a String in Haskell"]
```

`map words` makes `[["Split","a","String","in","Haskell"]]` from `["Split a String in Haskell"]`, and `concat` makes `[x]` from `[[x]]`. And `concat (map f xs)` is equal to `xs >>= f`. And `h xs = xs >>= f` is equal to `h = (>>= f)`.

Another way, more simple would be

```
split = words . head
```

Comment: i'm new to Haskell, and i'm not familiarized with the "(>>= words)" part. can you explain what it does ?

Comment: I'm not sure that second way would be more idiomatic since it uses `head`, a partial function.

Comment: @dcarou the function (>>=) is also available in the Prelude as `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`; it takes a function `a -> [b]` and applies it to all of the arguments of a list `[a]`, concatenating them all together into one big list `[b]`. You could also define it in terms of `.`, `concat`, and `map` as `concatMap = (concat .)  .  map`; when an `f` comes in this becomes `concat . map f` and when the `xs` come in you get `concat (map f xs)`.